# Do thread id's always fit into a four digit decimal number?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm writing log statements to a file and want to prepend each line with the thread id that generated the statement.

It appears that GetCurrentThreadId function always returns a number <= 9999. So, can I assume I can always format the thread id into a four digit string? I'd like to keep the id short and a consistent length to make the log files easier to read.

GetCurrentThreadId returns a DWORD which could obviously contain big numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not pad it to 4 digits if it's less, but allow more if necessary? Maybe a future OS version will invalidate your assumption even if it holds true now.

Comment: I suppose because if I coded for every possible future eventuality, I'd never finish and ship. I'm just interested in current OSs and  Windows8. I'm happy to just-in-time fix it up if it turns out more than 4 digits are needed on a future OS.

Comment: It's not like it's extra work to allocate a slightly longer string. And you SHOULD code according to the API specs so it won't have an easily avoidable crash in the next release.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I guess you are right. I initially thought a printf width specifier would crop the vale if it didn't fit, but that's not true.

Comment: How about using the thread name and keeping that to a standard length?

Comment: If there were thread names available, that might be good. The best info I can see about native thread names is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/vsdebug/thread/2a754d46-84d0-45ec-a7bf-58e22331e1c2.  Doesn't look easy and maybe not even possible.

Comment: @Wolf5370 Thread names were introduced as late as Windows 10 1607/Windows Server 2016 (see [`SetThreadDescription()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreaddescription)). Before that, thread names were simulated by the debugger. Client code would raise a specific exception that the debug engine understands and subsequently keep the mapping between thread ID and client-provided name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN page of GetCurrentThreadID says:

```
the thread identifier uniquely identifies the thread throughout the system.
```

So the thread id is unique across the system and not just your process, in which there is a good possibility that, it might at some time, return a value greater than a 4 digit decimal number.

Answer (score 3):

Why not write it as hex it will fit nicely in 8 digits then?

//Edit (Can't count!)

Comment: That would fit values up to 0xFFFF, but a DWORD can hold up to 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: Yes you are correct - DWORD is 32 bit, so would fit in 8 characters (Doh!). Still better than a huge number it could possibly be.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **no**.

Actually for 32 bit applications the (virtual) limit is around 2k threads. For 64 bit applications it's around 14k threads.

Read this article as quick reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markrussinovich/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads

This is the limit for the total number of threads (it's primary a problem of memory because of the stack of each thread) but there is not any rule about how thread ID is assigned (if your application creates a lot of short living threads then you *may* overflow this assumption).

Answer (score 1):

Give it another character space. It won't kill you and thread IDs are, as you mention, a DWORD and thus *could* be larger.